# Is a PhD in space-related technology from a Physics background possible?

Tags: physics, astronauts, esa, education, career

I am 24 years old, from Argentina. Next year I will finish my 6-year degree in physics from the University of Buenos Aires (We've been told that it is equivalent to a master's degree, but maybe is just a bit less).

My dream for years now has been to become an astronaut, so my question is:
Which universities should I be applying to for a PhD program in Space Technologu (aerospace or applied physics) coming from a non-engineering background?

I have European citizenship, so applying to the ESA would be the end goal, but would I be accepted given my background and age?

Edit: my ideas of what to do with my future are still really vague, thank you all for the advice and I wil probably ask a few questions in a few months.

Comment: Hi and welcome to space exploration stack exchange!  I’m not sure if this is the best forum for career/academic advice. Nonetheless, it might help if you can first answer: What do you envision doing with a PhD in “space technology”? And, possibly, what aspect of the technology do you want to apply your physics knowledge to? If you have concrete answers to these questions, advice *might* be possible.

Comment: In addition to what Paul says, I would suggest you ask one thing: your title asks about the possibility of doing a PhD, while the last line suggests you are asking about getting into a specific organization to work.

Comment: A PhD might or might not help. I don't know ESA's standards, but I have known multiple people who submitted themselves as candidate NASA astronauts, but none made it to the NASA astronaut candidate stage, aka ASCAN. Physical fitness is a necessity. If you don't run/jog/bike multiple km per day, start doing so, now.  If you don't know how to swim, take swimming lessons. Intelligence is a huge plus. A PhD is not necessarily a sign of intelligence but It is a sign of motivation and sticktoitiveness, both of which are huge, huge pluses. Knowledge is a big plus (a PhD does helps here).

Comment: Are you willing to die? This is a plus, maybe even a necessity. Do you not want to die? This is a necessity.

Comment: ESA is currently accepting astronaut applications, with the application window closing on 28 May 2021. They will receive tens of thousands of applications (or more) for the four to six slots they have open. Applicants will include used car salespeople (Seriously! "I sell cars for a living, but I have always wanted to be an rocket scientist." We've passed those resumes around for funsies.) But there will be hundreds of extremely qualified candidates. The completion is even stiffer for those very few ESA slots than it is for the NASA slots.

Comment: To add to David Hammen's excellent answer, I would encourage you to look at the profiles of ESA astronauts compared to US astronauts. In my experience, the anglosaxon world (US, UK) has a PhD fetish that is not shared by the continent: work experience and progression of responsibility with a willingness to take measured risk (SCUBA, private pilot license, parachuting) is probably more valued than just a PhD and a closet job.

Comment: Thanks to all your answers. I have accepted an edit in my original thread that changed a bit the message.

Just to clarify a few things, when I say space technology, I mean anything that, as a physicist, I can do within the production of new satellites, space craft,etc.

I know that a PhD is not an automatic seal of approval, but I also know it helps, and frankly I would like to do it.

Do not get me wrong, I do not plan on doing a "closet job" as Chris said. I'm more of doing things with my hands, at least in a lab, but being all day in front of the computer is not my thing

Comment: I really have to make up my mind. My ideas are still vague. Ill come back later,in a few months. Thanks for the advice